# GIT Bash Error when trying to generate SSH key

Tags: bash, ssh, git

I am using the following link:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

When I copy and paste: `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`, substituting my own github email within the quotations, I receive an error.

Here is what I have pasted and the error I have received:

```
$ $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
bash: $: command not found
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

#### Can anyone help me out?

> When I copy and paste: `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

You have copied the `$` which is the command prompt.

What you should be pasting is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Without the leading `$`.